# For Loop isn't working in C. It ends before it should

Tags: c, for-loop, uri

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define tam 10

int main()
{
    int N, i;
    char name[tam], name2[tam];
    char name3[] = {"ataque"};
    char name4[] = {"pedra"};
    char name5[] = {"papel"};

    scanf("%d", &N); // Entrada do número de repetições

    for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {

        fgets(name, tam, stdin); // Entrada de dados
        fgets(name2, tam, stdin);

        if (strncmp(name, name3, 6) == 0)
        { // Comparação das strings para saber o resultado
            if (strcmp(name, name2) == 0)
                printf("Aniquilicao mutua\n");
            else
                printf("Jogador 1 venceu\n");
        }

        else if (strncmp(name, name4, 5) == 0)
        { // Outra possibilidade
            if (strcmp(name, name2) == 0)
                printf("Sem ganhador\n");
            else if (strncmp(name2, name3, 6) == 0)
                printf("Jogador 2 venceu\n");
            else
                printf("Jogador 1 venceu\n");
        }

        else if (strncmp(name, name5, 5) == 0)
        {
            if (strcmp(name, name2) == 0)
                printf("Ambos venceram\n");
            else
                printf("Jogador 2 venceu\n");
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I don't know why but the loop isn't working until the end "}". It's reading only the first "fgets" and it ends there. It should read until the last "else if". Can somebody help me, please?

Comment: Provide the *exact* input you're using in your question.

Comment: Don't combine `scanf` and `fgets`.

Comment: https://www.beecrowd.com.br/judge/en/problems/view/2031 the code it's from this question, so are the inputs @WhozCraig

Comment: @dbush I'm starting to code and learn strings now, why can't I use scanf and fgets together? Thank you for the help.

Comment: See the linked dup.